# Message not recieved in cloud pub/sub Receiver

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a spring boot application in which I am creating a subscriber by passing subscription id at the time of application start

```java
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.MessageReceiver;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.ProjectSubscriptionName;
...
...
public void startAndWait() {
ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName = ProjectSubscriptionName.of(projectName, subscriptionId);
Subscriber subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, receiver).build();
log.log(Level.INFO, "Created Subscriber: " + subscriptionName); // I get this logger message when service starts
subscriber.startAsync();
    }
```

Following is the code for receiver that is passed to this subscriber while initialization in above code.

```java
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.AckReplyConsumer;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.MessageReceiver;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;
..
..
@Log
@Component
@Configurable
public class SubMessageReceiver implements MessageReceiver {
..
..
@Override
    public void receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) {

try {
   processMessage(message);
} catch (IOException e) {
   log.log(Level.SEVERE, "retrieving message content failed");
} catch (Exception e) {
   log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed triggering rules");
}
   consumer.ack();
}
```

I tried - manually deleting and again creating subscriptions, Manually publishing multiple messages on the topic and verified that those are received by subscription on google cloud console.
The only issue is the receiveMessage method from client library is not getting the message ever! 
I verified that there is no other subscriber with the same subscription id I am using (not on any other environments either)
I verified that the message queue is not full with unAcked messages.

I am expecting some loggers printed in my processMessage method mentioned above, or when I place debugger inside this method it should stop at the debug pointer whenever message arrives.

Please support or post any ideas! TIA!

Comment: Have you tried adding a log statement to the try block as well before processMessage()? You wouldn't expect any of the existing print statements to print unless an exception occurred. Also make sure you've instantiated the correct MessageReceiver. See the following for Subscriber examples https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/969bbeef18f004fd51fd46c5def1ae5c644cae3c/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/pubsub/snippets/SubscriberSnippets.java

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was able to make it work by downgrading the version. Updated in answer to this question.

Comment: It works in my local but on in my QA environment. Any idea why it would happen? @ShalakaDeshpande

Answer (score 2):

There was no change in the code but I was able to make it work with downgrading version of google pub/sub maven library.

```java
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
            <version>1.56.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now it works as expected for all the messages on the given topic.
Hope it will help someone.